# Change No Data Value Geotif File with Qgis or Gdal

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a little question for Change No Data Value Geotiff File with Qgis or Gdal by another value. Usually one imports or exports a file with no data value -9999, but sometimes we need to change that number for another on raster calculator the expression != but it seems not to work with No data value
any idea

---

Nice discussion, Carlos  but at same Kurt this option is for a range of data.
I was user syntax band math of ENVI and I thought to apply something like this on 
Raster Calculator

```
( "MCD10A1_2018266@1" != -9999) * -8888 AND  ( "MCD10A1_2018266@1" >=  0 )  * "MCD10A1_2018266@1"
```

But I do not understand does not work!!

Comment: Use https://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html with `-a_nodata`.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility

You could to use this tool
Menu >>  Raster >> Conversion >> Translate (convert format)

And assign the new value to no-data values,

[image]

Comment: does also not work for me: a "no data" value cant be set to a valid value e.g. 0 or 100 or whatever

Answer (score 4):

To change `No Data` values of a raster to something else, like 0 or 1 or whatever, you can use the GRASS tool `r.null`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

basename=$(echo "$1" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
mask=${basename}_mask.tif
output=${basename}_edt.tif
nodata=$(gdalinfo $1 | grep "NoData" | cut -d "=" -f 2)
gdal_calc.py --NoDataValue=$2 --calc="A!=${nodata}" --outfile="$mask" -A $1
gdal_calc.py --NoDataValue=$2 --calc="A*B" --outfile="$output" -A $1 -B $mask
```

First it gets the current no data value, then it creates a mask where the data is set as 1 and then multiplies that mask to get new image where no data is set with a parameter.

To run it just write it e.g. as `gdal_change_nodata.sh` and run it typing:

`bash gdal_change_nodata.sh PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE.tif NEW_NO_DATA_VAL`

or just change the values of `$1` param by the path to your original file and $2 by the no data value that you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

when you export the raster, context menu

"Export --> Export Raster Layer As..."

You could to change the no data value, see the picture

From -99999 To -88888 (per example)

[image]

Comment: did NOT work for me, when you have "no data" instead of say -9999

Comment: replace -99999 for the value that your raster use to "No data value"

Comment: See the Layer properties (your raster) >> Information >> Bands >> No-Data

Comment: ah , Layer properties (your raster) >> Information >> Bands >> No-Data  shows which value is used for no data, thx

Comment: Is there a way to recode a "no data"-value to a valid value, e.g. 0 ?

Comment: Perhaps it works if you fill "From" in blanc (null)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to accomplish this within a Python script using GDAL personally. The following script worked for me

```py
dataset = gdal.Open('path/to/image.tif')
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(2**16 - 1) # my No Data value was '65536'.. or 2^16 - 1
dataset.FlushCache()
del dataset
```